# Supabase: Query returning an object instead of an array

Tags: next.js, supabase, supabase-database

Does anyone know why the following supabase query would return an Object instead of an Array?

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
    var today = new Date();
    today = today.toISOString().split('T')[0];

    const { books, error } = await supabase.from('books').select('*').gt('published', today).limit(10).order('published', { ascending: true }) 

    if (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }
    
    return {
        props: {
            books
        }
    };
}
```

In the browser console.log this is returning

```
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

instead of

```
[[Prototype]]: Array
```

I want the results to return an Array as expected, so I can use the map function.

Any help gratefully received! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note.  The array I need is actually contained within the object and I had to access it via books.books.  Just feels weird that I don't have to do that with any other supabase query.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out.

I had

```
export default function Home(books) {
```

instead of

```
export default function Home({books}) {
```